# Maximise the modulus of product of a constant and a variable

Tags: combinatorics, modular-arithmetic

I need a formula to calculate the maximum sum of products of variable and constant and the whole sum will be then performed a modulus by some number.

X = (C1*x1 + C2*x2 + C3*x3..... )%M, we have to maximise 'X' here, the values of Ci and M is given, all xi are variables (any integer, zero included), in short I can say we have to vary the xi's such that we get maximum possible X, for example

X = (10*i + 3*j)%18  (here i and j are variables)

answer :- X = 17 (take j = 1 and i = 5)

Does any formula exists to find the maximum possible value of X ?

sorry if you didn't understand the question (my English is not good), if you have any doubts ask in the comments section

Comment: no, the variables have to be strictly non-negative integers (only positive number and zero)

Comment: but still you may share your formula

Comment: so this formula is for negative integers as you said?

Comment: will it work for positive integers?

Comment: where is the modulus ??

Comment: ok I edited the question u may post a well documented answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum positive value attainable with integers $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_i$ and positive integers $C_1,C_2,\dots,C_i$ is $k=\min{(\{z:z=\gcd{(C_j,C_k)}\land j,k\in\{1,2,\dots,i\}\})}$, and the maximum value of $X$ in this case is $\max{(\{k,2k,3k,\dots,(M−1)k\})}\mod{M}$. In other words, the maximum positive value of
$$C_1x_1+C_2x_2+\dots+C_ix_i\mod{M}$$
with positive integers $C_1,C_2,\dots$ and $M$ is
$$X\equiv\max{(\{k,2k,3k,\dots,(M−1)k\})} \mod{M}$$
where $k$ is the lowest possible greatest common denominator of a pair of integers from $C_1,C_2,\dots,C_i$ i.e
$$k=\min{(\{z:z=\gcd{(C_j,C_k)}\land j,k\in\{1,2,\dots,i\}\})}$$

Comment: and C1, C2 …. Ci are also positive values so I don't think we need to find the max{k,2k,3k,…,(M−1)k}

Comment: and also can you share links from where I can study them or recommend me any book or PDF

Comment: The only thing that I used is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity

Comment: I actually stated the solution incorrectly, the edit I just made correctly states the solution.